# Too much horizontal space in Bootstrap 4 nabvbar with centered image in nav links?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make links in Bootstrap navbar with an image as background, such that the text of the link is centered in the image.

The image and text positioning is correct, but there is some strange horizontal space between nav links, and I've not been able to figure out where it's coming from. Any help?

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/4zghtcd0/

```css
.planet {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.planet img {
    width: 10%;
}

.planet a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <span class="planet" style="top: -1rem">
                        <img src="https://www.goodfreephotos.com/cache/vector-images/kawaii-earth-vector-clipart_800.jpg" />
                        <a class="nav-link active">HOME</a>
                    </span>
                    <!--<a class="nav-link" href="#">home</a>-->
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">|</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">BAR</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your `.planet img { width: 10%; }` is messing with the layout, if you use `.planet img { width: 100px; }` for example it works

Comment: @Lucas Thank you! With that fix it becomes exactly as I wanted.